# How can I send push notification to mobile devices acccording to their clicks of Activity?

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, google-analytics, push-notification

I am developing mobile application where I should send notifications to specified users. For example, I have products and their categories, and you can see products by category.

I should send notifications for users, for example that chose "Category 1" more than 5 times. How I can realize it? All categories are in one page and their are on expandable list view control.
Using mobile OS: Android and iOS.

I used Google Analytics for Analytics to take clicks for Activity, but not for categories, and I used parse.com, but there I have not found what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in Cloud Code at Parse.com and then when a user choose category 5 times, you call this function which will send a push notification for the user.

Comment: thank you for reply! but my question about how to count clicks with parse.com, and when send notificaiton send this message to people who really pressed 5 or times. Is it called segmented notification?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to save information about viewed category on your server and then notify the user via Google Cloud Messaging. It is possible in case when your users are registered. If no, you could try to use cookies to store information about viewed categories.